# using .html() breaks .click() and .hover() events

Tags: jquery

I've a situation where I need to change the src of an image using jquery. I know the ID of the div and I know the format of the file name (I need to change _over to _main) but the src of the image is the only unique identifier.

My solution was to use .html() and .replace to change the image and this worked. However it had the unwelcome side effect of breaking any .hover() and .click() events associated with the image. Is there a way to restore these events or a better way of changing the img src that doesn't break them (bearing in mind I can only ID the image through the src)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [$.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

it breaks because you're replacing the elements, and thus they're losing their click handlers. if you use `.live` instead of `.bind` (or its short-forms, like `.click`), it will work on all future elements as well.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing

```
$('selector').click(function() {})
```

do it like this

```
$('selector').live('click', function() {})
```

This will preserv the events even if object is altered.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably be just changing the src attribute instead of using html() that essentially is replacing the whole img tag.

```
 $("#divID img").attr("src", "new/image/path");
```

If not, you should be using [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to preserve the attached event.